# Is it worth adding an Azure Cache for Redis instance Output Cache provider to a single instance Web App?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, caching, redis

I have a single instance ASP.NET MVC website running on Azure. I'm working on improving its speed.

ASP.NET Output Caching was added for faster page loads, with good results.

I was reading up on the possibility of using an Azure Redis instance as the Output Cache.

My thinking is:

- Default Output Cache is the best for single instance apps, it should be the fastest because it runs on the same machine
- Azure Redis Cache would most likely be slower, since it would add an extra cache lookup roundtrip between the Web App and the Redis instance

Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, given that all of your requests are being processed within the same application it's sufficient to use in-memory caching.

Azure Redis Cache would be beneficial if you had multiple processes which all wanted to share the same cache, e.g. if your website was running across multiple containers.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are trying to achieve. In memory cache will be quicker than Redis but lets say you restart your app and the cache would need to be refreshed. |In cases, where you have large reference data which you are caching, this might be an overhead. You can use a combination of in memory and Redis in such a case, which will also act as a fail safe in case something goes wrong.